# Is logic like this possible in php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one describe a rock-paper-scissors relationship between 3 items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717149/how-can-one-describe-a-rock-paper-scissors-relationship-between-3-items)

Hi guys im doing a php task for a rock paper scissors game, im trying to do the rule check part and want to use logic like this ruby function below, im trying to avoid conditionals where possible.

Any one have any ideas ?

```
def who_wins(p1, p2)
  win_moves = {"rock" => "paper", "paper" => "scissors", "scissors" => "rock"}
  ([p1, p2] & win_moves.values_at(p1, p2)).first
end

who_wins("rock", "paper") # "paper"
who_wins("scissors", "rock") # "rock"
who_wins("scissors", "scissors") # nil
```

Comment: See here: [How can one describe a rock-paper-scissors relationship between 3 items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717149/how-can-one-describe-a-rock-paper-scissors-relationship-between-3-items), Lusitanian's answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick function that I made:

```
function who_wins($p1, $p2){
    $win_moves = array("rock" => "paper", "paper" => "scissors", "scissors" => "rock");
    if($p1 === $p2){
        return null;
    }
    return ($win_moves[$p1] === $p2) ? $p2 : $p1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The only condition is when $p1 and $p2 are the same. The logic is handled with array functions.

```
function who_wins($p1, $p2) {
    if ($p1 === $p2) {
        return "nil";
    }
    $actions = array("rock", "scissors", "paper");

    $selected_actions = array_merge(array_keys($actions, $p1), array_keys($actions, $p2));
    sort($selected_actions);

   return $actions[$selected_actions[0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your original function does, but here's a pretty compact solution
I'm sure with some more loving you could rid the if statement.

```
<?php
echo who_wins("rock", "paper")."\n";
echo who_wins("scissors", "rock")."\n";
echo who_wins("scissors", "scissors")."\n";

function who_wins($p1,$p2) {
    $comb = array (
    "rock"  => 0,
    "paper" => 1,
    "scissors"  => 2,
    );

    $result = (3+$comb[$p1]-$comb[$p2]) % 3;

    if ($result==1){ return $p1; } elseif($result==2) { return $p2; } 

}
?>
```